# Upper-bound on energy of nonlinear boundary value problem (Hard!)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, integral-inequality

**The problem:**

Consider the following boundary-value problem for the function $\rho : \mathbb{R}^{+} \to  \mathbb{R}$ with boundary conditions $\lim_{x\to \infty}\rho(x) \to 1$  and $\lim_{x\to 0}\rho(x) \to \infty$:

$$\rho^{\prime \prime}-\frac{\rho^{\prime 2}}{\rho}+\frac{\rho^{\prime}}{x}+\frac{\kappa^2}{x^2 \rho}-\rho^2 f(\rho)=0
$$

where $\kappa \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant and

$$
f(\rho) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-(\rho-1)}(\rho-1)(3-\rho)
$$

Define the "energy" of the solution

$$
E = \int _0^\infty  x \left(\frac{\rho'}{\rho}\right)^2 dx
$$

**By playing around numerically, I am led to the following conjecture: $E =O(\kappa)$ for small $\kappa$**.

---

**A very quick analysis:**

- I will not attempt to prove that a solution exists, nor do I ask for such an argument. In the following I assume that a solution exists.
- The asymptotic form at small $x$ is $\rho \sim -\kappa \ln(\alpha x)$ for some constant $\alpha$. Assuming this approximate form for $x<x_I$, the energy is at least (roughly)

$$
\int_0 ^{x_I} \frac{1}{x(\ln(\alpha x))^2} = - \frac{1}{\ln(\alpha x_I)} \sim  \frac{\kappa}{\rho}
$$

- Numerically, it appears that $\rho$ is monotonically decreasing. Assuming this is true, then it follows  $\rho>1$, such that the $x<x_I$ contribution to the energy is $O(\kappa)$.
- The large $x$ asymptotic form is $\rho \sim 1+ \frac{\kappa^2}{x^2} +O(\frac{1}{x^3})$. Assuming this is valid for $x>x_O$, the large $x$ contribution to the energy is to leading order

$$
\int_{x_O} ^{\infty} x(2\kappa^2/x^3)^2 dx = \left(\frac{\kappa^2}{x_O^2}\right)^2 
$$

- Depending on when the large $x$ asymptotic form becomes valid, this contribution may be $O(1)$ (or larger) or $O(\kappa)$, though my numerics suggest this contribution is at most $O(\kappa^2)$, such that in total $E = O(\kappa)$.

---

**In summary:** is it true that $E=O(\kappa)$ for small $\kappa$? Can it at least be proven that $E=O(\kappa^n)$ for some $n>0$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann This problem seems up your alley. I was wondering if the method of matched asymptotic expansions might work here to at least gain some approximate insight. Numerically, it seems quite difficult to probe very small \kappa as any collocation method must then have a very small tolerance due the behavior at the large x boundary. Python's scipy.bvp cannot seem to go lower than  \kappa=1e-2, because the solution would need to be accurate to more than 10 digits, but standard Python only has 16 digit accuracy. Thus I would be curious if you have any further numerical insight here.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions.

You can eliminate some of the nonlinearities by setting $\rho= e^u$ and $x= e^t$. Then the energy integral becomes just the usual one:

(1) $E= \int (\dot u)^2 dt$

and the differential equation becomes

(2) $\ddot u + k^2 e^{-2u} = e^{2t} e^u f(e^u)$.

If your conjecture  is indeed true that $u$ is monotone decreasing, then after multiplying (2) by $\dot u$ and integrating, perhaps you get a useful estimate on the behavior of $(\dot u )^2$.

It might help to first consider the case where the RHS of (2) is **zero** since your choice of $f(\rho)$ appears to approach zero asymptotically as $t\to +\infty$. In this case you can solve (2) exactly.

Comment: thanks, I did try this approach at first, but it did not lead to any useful estimates because the RHS (after multiplying by \dot{u} is not integrable. It is true that the integral of the RHS is negative if u is monotonically decreasing, but the issue is I have no control over the constant of integration of the LHS.